# Proper alignment of plot labels with respect to individual curves

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, legending

I have the following plot problem:

```
δ2[α_, x0_, x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < x0 - α ∨ x > x0}, {1/α, x0 - α <= x <= x0}}]
α = {1, 1/2, 1/5};
exprs = δ2[#, 2, x] & /@ α;
exprstxt = StringJoin[
             ToString[Subscript[δ, #], FormatType -> StandardForm],
             "(x-2)"
            ] & /@ α;
labels = MapThread[Style, {exprstxt, Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], Length[exprstxt]]}];
Plot[exprs, {x, -1, 3}, Exclusions -> None, PlotLabels -> Placed[labels, Above]]
```

Which results in:
[image]

Is there a way to properly align the `Labels` with the particular curves. I am giving up on some logical alignment line to the left with respect to the peak but at least so that they are not on top of each other. I tried e.g. `Bottom` which is ridiculous since all are probably on top of each other. Also, is there a way to say "Above + {1,2} pt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\[Delta]2[\[Alpha]_, x0_, x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, x < x0 - \[Alpha] \[Or] x > x0}, {1/\[Alpha], 
    x0 - \[Alpha] <= x <= x0}}]
\[Alpha] = {1, 1/2, 1/5};
exprs = \[Delta]2[#, 2, x] & /@ \[Alpha];
exprstxt = 
  StringJoin[
     ToString[Subscript[\[Delta], #], FormatType -> StandardForm], 
     "(x-2)"] & /@ \[Alpha];
labels = MapThread[
   Style, {exprstxt, 
    Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], Length[exprstxt]]}];
Show[{
  Plot[exprs, {x, -1, 3}, Exclusions -> None],
  Graphics[{Text[labels[[1]], {0.91, 1.32`}], 
    Text[labels[[2]], {1.436, 2.35`}], Text[labels[[3]], {1.5, 4.9}]
    }]
  }]
```

[image]

Have fun!